# Properly build a git submodule with gnu make

Tags: git, makefile, gnu-make, git-submodules

I currently try to write a Makefile that build properly a project which contains a git submodule. This submodule have its own set of makefiles and produce several targets at once, including some libraries.

This Makefile should have the following properties.

- Don't rebuild twice the submodule even with parallel build.
- Update the submodule targets when the submodule code has changed (maybe
  because I navigated through the revisions of the main repository).
- Re-link the main project when the submodule library have changed.
- Don't copy-paste the Makefiles of the submodule in the top-level project (i.e. keep the Makefiles recursive).

Just to set the ideas, here is something that seems to work.

```
FOO_SUBDIR := $(CURDIR)/foo
LDFLAGS := -L$(FOO_SUBDIR)

FOO_LIBSFILES := $(FOO_SUBDIR)/libfoo.a $(FOO_SUBDIR)/libgnufoo.a
FOO_LDLIBS := -lfoo -lgnufoo


.PHONY: all
all: main

# There are theoretically 3 main binaries
main: main.c $(FOO_LIBSFILES)
    gcc -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS) $(FOO_LDLIBS)

$(FOO_LIBSFILES): libfoo
    @# Do nothing

.PHONY: libfoo
libfoo:
    $(MAKE) -C $(FOO_SUBDIR)
```

It seems to work sice I added the empty recipe, but I don't understand why.

The idea is to always rely on the submodule's Makefile to rebuild (or not) `libfoo.a` and `libgnufoo.a`, and let the main Makefile decide whether `main` need to be rebuilt. Without the empty recipe it doesn't work. When a `foo/foo.c` is modified, then `libfoo.a` is rebuilt, but `make` doesn't rebuild `main`.

I have the feeling that the empty recipe force make to check the date of the target files. But I can't find documentation about this behavior.

Is this the right way to go? Any pitfall I should be aware of? Any less obscure way to do this? Or any documentation about this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct in general - in your toplevel makefile you've added targets that works the subproject. It is the only proper way to work with a standalone (sub-)project, via its own makefile.

The specific problem you are asking about has to do with not terminating the libfoo dependent rule, and GNU make requires a rule to have commands, even if it is a no-op. Do this instead:

```
$(FOO_LIBSFILES): libfoo ;
```

This is effectively the same no-op, but more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So you mean that this behavior is not really hackish and should work in the long run?

Comment: @Celelibi Not sure which behaviour you refer to, but introducing a target to represent a sub-project is not hackish. Having no-op targets is not hackish as well.

Comment: I'm refering to the fact that the rule for `$(FOO_LIBSFILES)` do not touch these files. Instead it's the rule `libfoo` that does it. And I force make to check the file dates by giving an empty recipe.

Comment: @Celelibi This is the cleaner approach in my opinion. A single target that deals with a single sub-project via its make file. Other targets depend on it - I see no problem with this.