# make dependency on all files in a subdirectory (git submodule)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to write a (GNU) make rule that depends on the existence of some file (any arbitrary file) in a subdirectory.  In my specific case, that subdirectory is a git submodule.

This is what I have:

```
DEP = submod/.git

$(DEP):
        git submodule update --init $(@D)

submod/%: | $(DEP)
        @ # why do I need this?

install: submod/junk.c
        echo installing
```

If I then type `make install`, the git command is run (change it to `mkdir -p $(@D); touch $@` for a non-git-specific test), and make doesn't complain.

I have two questions.  Primarily, are there any side effects to the dummy recipe for `submod/%` I should be concerned about?  Secondly, and more interestingly, why do I need that recipe at all?  If I remove it, make errors out:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'submod/junk.c', needed by 'install'.  Stop.
```

My only hypothesis is that make is doing some optimization based on the files that exist at startup, and with the no-recipe version, it thinks that it can just expect the file to exist when it's needed, but with any recipe there, it can't do that optimization, and it reevaluates when it's needed.  If that's true, is it a bug, or something that should be changed?

Comment: The recipe is not dummy. It tells make that if it needs a file in the `submod` subdirectory, and if `submod/.git` does not exist, it must make it first. By removing it you leave make without a clue on how to make `submod/junk.c` that `install` depends on, if it does not exist.

Comment: _are there any side effects to the dummy recipe_: as explained in my other comment the rule is not dummy. Its side effect is that if `submod/.git` does not exist, and make needs a file in the `submod` subdirectory, it must make `submod/.git` first. As `$(DEP)` is an order-only prerequisite, only its existence matters, not its last modification time if it exists already.

Comment: I guess I'm still not sure why the dependency on `$(DEP)` isn't enough. The fact that it's order-only shouldn't matter (and doesn't seem to). I would think that when make needs to have `submod/whatever` exist, it would see that rule, note that `$(DEP)` doesn't exist, and go make it. But perhaps it expects that if `submod/whatever` doesn't exist, it needs an actual recipe that builds it directly, rather than doing so indirectly through a dependency. That explains the behavior, at least in my head.

Comment: There's also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806682/properly-build-a-git-submodule-with-gnu-make which I'd not found previously.